# How to create a function which creates table in VBA?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, function

I want to code a function my_table(x_0, x_1, x_2) which outputs table containing three rows and one column. In first row it should have x_0, in second x_1, and x_2 in last one.

**My work so far**

```
Function my_table()

    Dim arr(3) As Variant
    
    arr(0) = x_0
    arr(1) = x_1
    arr(2) = a
    
    my_table = Application.Transpose(arr)
    

End Function 

my_table(1,2,3)
```

[image]

AS you can see it's working as it should be. However I found my solution inefficient because I create array and transpose it instead of creating table at the very beggining. My question is : is there any possiblity to code this function, without creating transformed array - just table from the beggining containing x_0, x_1, x_2 ?

Comment: What do you mean by "table"? Do you like inserting a 'ListObject` table and populate it with he array value, or simple paste an array value to the sheet and name the range where it has been pasted as 'table'?

Comment: By table I meant ListObject ;))

Comment: Then, test the code I posted and send some feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You could just declare a 2D array to start with:

```
Dim arr(1 to 3, 1 to 1) As Variant

arr(1, 1) = x_0
arr(2, 1) = x_1
arr(3, 1) = a
my_table = arr
```

Answer (score 0):

### Create an Array of Values

**A Quick Fix**

```
Function my_table(x_0, x_1, a)
    Dim arr(1 To 3, 1 To 1)
    arr(1, 1) = x_0
    arr(2, 1) = x_1
    arr(3, 1) = a
    my_table = arr
End Function
```

**A More Flexible Solution**

```
Function createColumnOfValues(ParamArray Vals() As Variant) As Variant
    Dim Data As Variant: ReDim Data(1 To UBound(Vals) + 1, 1 To 1)
    Dim n As Long
    For n = 0 To UBound(Vals)
        Data(n + 1, 1) = Vals(n)
    Next n
    createColumnOfValues = Data
End Function

Sub TESTcreateColumnOfValues()
    Dim Data As Variant: Data = createColumnOfValues(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(Data)
        Debug.Print Data(i, 1)
    Next i
    'or e.g.:
    'Range("A1").Resize(UBound(Data, 1)).Value = Data
End Sub
```

**Test With Table (EDIT)**

```
Sub testWithHeader()
    With Sheet1
        ' Write values to array.
        Dim Data As Variant: Data = createColumnOfValues(1, 2, 3)
        ' Define range ('+ 1' for header).
        Dim rng As Range: Set rng = .Range("A1").Resize(UBound(Data) + 1)
        ' Write header.
        rng(1).Value = "Header"
        ' Write body.
        rng(2).Resize(UBound(Data)).Value = Data
        ' Convert to table.
        .ListObjects.Add _
            SourceType:=xlSrcRange, _
            Source:=rng, _
            XlListObjectHasHeaders:=xlYes
    End With
End Sub

Sub testWithoutHeader()
    With Sheet1
        ' Write values to array.
        Dim Data As Variant: Data = createColumnOfValues(1, 2, 3)
        ' Define range.
        Dim rng As Range: Set rng = .Range("A1").Resize(UBound(Data))
        ' Write values from array to range.
        rng.Value = Data
        ' Convert to table ('Column1' will be used as the header).
        .ListObjects.Add _
            SourceType:=xlSrcRange, _
            Source:=rng, _
            XlListObjectHasHeaders:=xlNo
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the next code, please:

```
Sub insertTable()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, tbl As ListObject, arr, i As Long
  
  ReDim arr(1 To 5, 1 To 1)
  For i = 1 To 5
    arr(i, 1) = "X_" & i
  Next i
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  
  Set tbl = sh.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=xlSrcRange, Source:=sh.Range("A1:A5"))
  With tbl
    .Name = "testTable"
    .DataBodyRange.cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(arr), UBound(arr, 2)).Value = arr
  End With
End Sub
```

The next piece of code, creates a two columns Table and drop the array value in them:

```
Sub insertTableTwoColumns()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, tbl As ListObject, arr, i As Long, j As Long
  
  ReDim arr(1 To 5, 1 To 2)
  For i = 1 To 5
    For j = 1 To 2
        If j = 2 Then
            arr(i, j) = "Y_" & i
        Else
            arr(i, j) = "X_" & i
        End If
    Next j
  Next i
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  
  Set tbl = sh.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=xlSrcRange, Source:=sh.Range("M1:M2"))
  With tbl
    .Name = "testTable2"
    .DataBodyRange.cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(arr), UBound(arr, 2)).Value = arr
  End With
End Sub
```

The table can be created with only a row and a column. When resizing to drop the array value, it automatically adds the necessary rows and columns.

Comment: @John: Didn't you find some time to test the answers code? If tested, some feedback should not kill anybody... :)